# one server missing a SYSVOL policy object

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sysvol

one of my DCs is missing a single GPO object - all others are there and appear to be the correct version.  there are no errors related to DFS or FRS in event viewer that i can find.

the server in question is 2008, although there are both 2003 and 2008 DCs in this domain.

repadmin shows no errors that i can find.

update:

ok so now its looking more like GPOs created on a specific server (one of the 2008 boxes) arent syncing out to the others. i thought i had seen this GPO on other servers, but its not there now. dcdiag and repadmin show no errors besides the userenv GPO processing errors still, but userenv is complaining all over the logs on multiple machines

update2:

solved - this machine was out of sync and wasnt syncing using frs at all - these errors werent showing up in eventvwr for some reason.  performed scandisks on both drives at startup, and it started logging ntfrs error 13552, 13555.  was able to rebuild using BURFLAG registry key.

Comment: More than 1 site, or a single site?

Comment: Also try a *dcdiag* on both domain controllers and see if you get any errors with that.

Comment: single site, although the one in question is physically further away than the rest

Comment: dcdiag pointed out some errors i missed in eventlog, thanks nixphoe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `dcdiag` on each of the domain controllers and see if you get any errors to look into with that command

Comment: ive resolved everything dcdiag found except for the one indicating that the server could not locate the gpt.ini in question.  is it safe to just create a directory with the correct GUID and copy the files i know should be in there to that location?

Comment: Try forcing a replication and see if it gives you any errors in the event log.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816926(WS.10).aspx

Comment: no errors posted, dialog box says 'the active directory service has successfully replicated the connections'.

Comment: Ok, which server isn't replicating with which server? It sounds like you might have more than 2 DCs. Which server(s) have the GPO, 2008 or 2003?

Comment: we have 4 DCs, 2 2008r2, 2 2003.  one of the 2008r2 boxes isnt syncing with the other 3 (which are syncing fine).

Comment: If you create a new test group policy will that replicate to all servers?

Comment: Here's a few momre commands you could try to see if anything sticks out at you. http://serverfault.com/questions/283544/active-directory-authenication-and-sites

Comment: ok so now its looking more like GPOs created on a specific server arent syncing out to the others.  i thought i had seen this GPO on other servers, but its not there now.  dcdiag and repadmin show no errors besides the userenv GPO processing errors still, but userenv is complaining all over the logs on multiple machines

Comment: If you have an update. Put it in your original post, someone might have seen the behavior before.